# update iframe src inside bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i have datatable rows have button with array value every thing is ok but iframe not updated inside modal it keeps show the first value inside iframe
how can update source inside modal

```
  <td>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <?php echo base_url('dash/course_price/'.$c->c_id);?>
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div
  class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button   type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe
        src="<?php echo base_url('dash/course_price/'.$c->c_id);?>"
        width="100%"  height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js and css :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is the javascript where you update the src of the iframe?

Comment: i have no js to update the src of iframe

Comment: You can use JavaScript or jQuery for Dom manipulation.